# How to disable particular ACE editor CSS-mode warning rules?

Tags: javascript, css, ace-editor, react-ace

My project makes use of the [Ace Editor](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) (via [Brace](https://github.com/thlorenz/brace) and [React-Ace](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace)).

We set the `mode` of the editor to `"css"` and embed it in our page. This works just fine, however, by default, we find some of the enabled CSS rule highlighting to be too stringent—some warnings should be "info"; some errors should be "warnings".

How can we disable/enable/modify the set of validation rules used for Info, Error, and Warnings by the Ace Editor in CSS mode?

I believe I've found [a relevant line of code in the Ace CSS worker](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/f17f0751fc4c2bb73cd9340e9cbc02e4d979608f/src/worker-css.js#L8030) but I'm not sure how to make use of it, nor where to find an exhaustive list of what the validation rule names are, if I did know how to use this function.

The code below is essentially what we use to instantiate the react ace component...

```
import brace from 'brace';
import AceEditor from 'react-ace';
import 'brace/mode/css';
import 'brace/theme/monokai';

...
  <AceEditor
    theme="monokai"
    mode="css"
    showGutter={true}
    ...
  />
```

Comment: I believe I may have found the beginnings of a solution here: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/3768#issuecomment-421144888

Answer (score 4):

Figured out a solution thanks to a hint from [a closed ACE editor issue](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/3768#issuecomment-421144888).

When the editor loads, find a reference to the "worker" instance and call either the `setInfoRules` or `setDisabledRules` methods with a `"|"` separated list of CSS lint rules IDs. (For `React-Ace` the just-loaded editor can be accessed via the `onLoad` prop),

Since the CSS linter used by Ace is `csslint` the rule IDs relevant for disable/enabling are CSS lint. [See the CSS Lint rule list](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/rules).

The following code is how I did it...

```
const INFO_RULES = [
  // Disable "Heading (h2) has already been defined." warning
  'unique-headings',
  // Disable "Heading (h2) should not be qualified." warning
  'qualified-headings',
  'fallback-colors'
];

const DISABLED_RULES = [
  // Disable "Don't use adjoining classes." warning
  'adjoining-classes',
  // Disable "Rule doesn't have all its properties in alphabetical ordered." warning
  'order-alphabetical'
];

const onEditSessionInit = (editSession)=> {
  editSession.$worker.call('setInfoRules', [INFO_RULES.join('|')]) ;
  editSession.$worker.call('setDisabledRules', [DISABLED_RULES.join('|')]) ;
};

const CSSCodeEditor = (propse)=>
  <CodeEditor 
    mode="css"
    onLoad={(editor)=> {
      onEditSessionInit(editor.session);
    }}
    {...props} 
  />;
```

Hopefully this helps someone some day...